# Напечатать слова отличные от последнего введенного с четным количеством букв

Tags: c++, строки

Задан текст нужно напечатать слова отличные от последнего введенного с четным количеством букв. Реализовать нужно через string.   Пример: Строка: hi how hello dear how. Вывод:hi dear.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


int main() {
    std::vector <std::string> arr;
    std::string word;

    while (std::cin >> word)
        arr.push_back(word);

    std::cout << word << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Знаю как написать через char но не понимаю как реализовать в string

Comment: Напишите код как вы знаете.  Переделаем для  string

Comment: Можно пример ожидаемого вывода работы программы? Загляните так же в справку: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Строка: hi how hello dear how. Вывод:hi dear.

Comment: @user321113 добавьте все детали в сам вопрос с помощью кнопки "править"

Comment: @ARHovsepyan #include "stdafx.h" 
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
int main() {
 setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
 char S1[] = "hi hello dear how";
 char *tokenPtr;
 //char S2[];
 int x;
 tokenPtr = strtok(S1, " ");
 x = strlen(tokenPtr);
 if (x % 2 == 0)
  std::cout << tokenPtr << std::endl;
 while (tokenPtr)
 {
  tokenPtr = strtok(NULL, " ");
  if (tokenPtr)
   x = strlen(tokenPtr);
  if (x % 2 == 0 )
   std::cout << tokenPtr << std::endl;
 }
 delete tokenPtr;
 system("pause");
 return 0;
}

Comment: И почему же Вывод:hi dear.    для  hi how hello dear how.? А что другие слова не отличаются ничем от  dear?

Comment: Лишь условие четности слов мне не понятно для написания в string , как написать проверку на отличие от последнего слова я примерно понял. Как раз в данном коде я и написал в char формате вывод четных по буквам слов.@ARHovsepyan

Comment: @user321113 у string есть метод size(), который возвращает количество символов, чётное то число, которое делится без остатка на 2

Comment: @user321113, нужно было код дописать в вопрос, а не в комментариях.  Но кажется ваш код не соответствует условию задачи, поскольку вы сравниваете с первым словом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код, который, вы написали на языке С,  по моему не соответствует требованию задачи тем, что  нужно слова сравнивать с последным введенным словом, а не с первым. Дальше, пытаясь писать на С++, в используете std::vector, что тоже не соответствует требованию задачи, поскольку нужно реализовать через std::string, а последный имеет все возможности для отделения слов по разделителью.    Покажу на примере:

```
using std::string;
const string s = "int i = 1234  j = 456789 k = 123456  endl  endl";
//или  введите всю строку:  string s; getline(std::cin, s);
//теперь находим позицию последнего пробела
size_t k = s.find_last_of(' ');
//и берем последнее слово начиная от следующей позиции, и выполняем обьявления
string last_word = s.substr(++k),
        word;
size_t  first = 0, last = 0, word_size = 0;
while (first <= k) {
    //находим первый пробел в строке, начиная от начала слова
    last  = s.find(' ', first);
    // размер слова
    word_size = last - first;
    // подстрока от начала слова, с данным размером
    word = s.substr(first, word_size);
    //начало следующего слова, это позиция первого символа_непробела,
    // начиная от конца последнего слова
    first = s.find_first_not_of(' ', last);
    // и выполняем проверку, соответствующую условию задачи...
    if (!(word == last_word) && !(word.size() % 2))
       std::cout << word << endl;        
}
```

Будут выводиться только числа, поскольку  все другие слова имеют нечетное  количество сиволов, а `endl`  не отличается от последнего слова.  Если нужно, то можете выводить последнее слово тоже: `if(!(last_word.size() % 2))` `std::cout << last_word;`

P.S. По хорошему нужно в начале кода пропускать первые пробелы(ведь они вполне могут быть).  Ну и не пишите код в комментариях, лучше дописать в вопрос...